# How can hooks update the props passed to component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component which is being passed a prop and I need the component to update when the value of the prop is changed.

I've tried using the useEffect hook to watch both the props and prop.propIWantToChange but I can't get the update to pass to the component after it has rendered.

**App.js**

```
let tracker = true;

const handleChangeTracker = () => {
  tracker = !tracker
}

const App = props => {
  <React.Fragment>
    <button onClick={handleChangeTracker} >Change</button>
    <Component1 active={tracker} />
    <Component2 />
    <Component3 />
    <Component4 />
  </React.Fragment>
}
```

**Component1.js**

```
const Component1 = props => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.active)
  }, [props.active])

  return (  
    <div>{props.active && "You see this when its true"}</div>  
  )
}
```

When the button is clicked, I expect the value of tracker to switch between true and false.  I then want it to pass that new value down to Component1.  Currently it will change the value (I track it through console logs) but it will not pass the new value to the component.

Comment: the spelling of useEffect is wrong.

Comment: That was just a typo transferring code over, all is well on my end.

Comment: Yea, I have posted a solution. Try that and let me know if that works :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is not passing to the child component because your 'tracker' variable is not stored in state. The change of the value of state triggers a new render and not the change of the value of variable.

So when 'tracker' is updated in 'handleChangeTracker' it doesn't trigger a new render and hence the new value is not passed to the child component and hence no new render of the child component.

Solution is to save 'tracker' in a state and then update the state in 'handleChangeTracker'.

```
this.state = { tracker = true; }

const handleChangeTracker = () => {
  this.setState({
            tracker: !tracker
        })
}

const App = props => {
  <React.Fragment>
    <button onClick={handleChangeTracker} >Change</button>
    <Component1 active={this.state.tracker} />
    <Component2 />
    <Component3 />
    <Component4 />
  </React.Fragment>
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly!  I was unaware that the prop value being passed was required to be in state to cause a new render.  Thank you very much.